# How to send a notification to a AngularJS app from a Java app

Tags: java, angularjs

I have a weird problem. I have an angular app which should display data from a Java Rest API. My java rest API doesn't have all the time data because this data comes from others systems.

So I need somehow to notify Angular app if I have available data in my API and to make a request to a specific resource.

Something link this:

```
Other Systems sends data -----------> Java API receives data
Java API ---------------------------> Notify Angular about new data available(e.g POST x.x.x.x:4200/notifications)
Angular makes a request to ---------> Java API for the new resources (e.g GET x.x.x.x/api/newData)
```

I don't know how I can notify an angular app about this new data because in order to do this Angular should behave like a server.

If anyone has some ideas regarding this problem and maybe other suggestions it will help me very much.

Thank you.

Comment: angular or angularjs?

Comment: You need to asynchronously notify the client, from the server. This can be done with a lot of ways, like polling from the client for changes, or websockets. An easy solution is to use a socket.io server in your Java app, and a socket.io client on the client-side. Angular has nothing to do with those, but you can write a service that handles the socket.io callback or use observables.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon is angularjs. Sorry.

Comment: @K.Gkinis do you know where I can see an example? Is not very clear for me how should I connect this tow sockets.Thx

Comment: [This repo has an example for a Java server.](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio) If you can use node.js temporarily, you can follow the tutorial from [socket.io](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) in order to understand the library, and how to do this client side.